# django setting up ngnix with static and media files served in a sub domain

Tags: django, nginx

I managed to get ngnix configured and its running when i try doing things like mocorner.com/static but when I try static.mocorner.com its taking me to landing page.

Below is my ngnix config file, can anyone advise about how I can resolve this issue? plus how can I separate the logs for each static and media?

```
upstream backend {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
            listen   80;

            access_log /home/mocorner/moapps/mocorner/logs/static-nginx-access.log;
            error_log /home/mocorner/moapps/mocorner/logs/static-nginx-error.log;

            location / {
                        proxy_pass  http://backend;
                        include     /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        }
        location /static {
            root  /home/mocorner/moapps/mocorner/app/static;
    }
        location /media {
            root  /home/mocorner/moapps/mocorner/media;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
upstream backend {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com
    access_log /home/mocorner/moapps/mocorner/logs/static-nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/mocorner/moapps/mocorner/logs/static-nginx-error.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        include    /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name media.mydomain.com
    access_log /home/mocorner/moapps/mocorner/logs/media-access.log;
    error_log /home/mocorner/moapps/mocorner/logs/media-error.log;
    root /home/mocorner/moapps/mocorner/media;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name static.mydomain.com
    access_log /home/mocorner/moapps/mocorner/logs/static-access.log;
    error_log /home/mocorner/moapps/mocorner/logs/static-error.log;
    root /home/mocorner/moapps/mocorner/app/static;
}
```